# How can I get my onboard mic to work while I'm using my AMD video card for sound playback?

Tags: 12.04, sound, microphone

This is a really annoying issue that no one seems to have the answer for. I'm using the audio of my HDMI sound card (its a Radeon HD 5450) to hear sound and it works when I'm listening to music or watching things online.

But while I have that as the default device for playing audio, my microphone port on my Gigabyte GA-Z77-DS3H is silent. It registers sound when I look under Sound Settings, that little orange bar flicks up and down at the strum of a bass note but I hear nothing no matter what I do.

If anyone can help I'd be so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I *suggest* you to install Pulse Audio and try checking options in it.

in terminal `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` or use the software center